# Scope of variables in for loop c++ strange behavior

Tags: c++, copy-constructor, stdmap

I am declaring a variable inside of a for loop and on the second iteration the variable still exists BEFORE the declaration. Here is the code

```
std::map<std::string,Schema> schemas;
std::vector<std::string> schemaFolders = fileUtil.getSubFolders(BASE_FOLDER);

  for(int i = 0; i < schemaFolders.size(); i++){
          std::string folder(BASE_FOLDER);
          folder += "/";
          folder += schemaFolders[i];
          Schema  schema(folder);
          schema->loadDatabases();
          schemas[schemaFolders[i]] =  schema;
          std::cout<<std::endl<<schemas[schemaFolders[0]].getSchemaFolder()<<std::endl;
  }
```

So the schema variable gets instantiated the first time around when i am debugging and im on the first line in the for loop schema is a valid object with all of its members the same as in the first iteration. Then when I redeclare Schema schema(folder), the Schema stored in schemas in the first position is changed such that all previous entries in the map schemas refer to the same schema element (the last one created).

This seems crazy to me. I have solved the issue by declaring schema as a pointer instead and instantiating it with new. Then I make a copy using * schemaPtr into the map. This works but I am flabbergasted at this issue. Could this be a copy constructor issue? Below is the schema hed

```
class Schema {
public:
    Schema();
    Schema( const Schema& other );
    Schema& operator=(const Schema& );
    Schema(std::string);
    virtual ~Schema();
    bool createDatabase(std::string);
    Database * getDatabase(std::string);
    void loadDatabases();
    std::vector<std::string> getDatabases();
    std::string executeQuery(std::string);
    std::string getSchemaFolder(){ return this->schemaFolder;}
private:
    std::map<std::string,Database *> databases;
    //this is only while we have not implemented sessions this will need to become a map
    //that stores lots of different session parameters
    Database* curDb;
    std::string schemaFolder;
};
```

And the copy constructor

```
Schema::Schema( const Schema& other ){
    this->schemaFolder = other.schemaFolder;
    this->databases =  other.databases;
    this->curDb = other.curDb;

}
```

And the Equals operator

```
Schema & Schema::operator=(const Schema& other){
    this->schemaFolder = other.schemaFolder;
    this->databases =  other.databases;
    this->curDb = other.curDb;

    return *this;
}
```

Comment: Note that your debug logging output always index `0` and not `i`.

Comment: How `schema->loadDatabases();` supposed to work?

Comment: Please post an implementation of your `Schema& operator=(const Schema& );` as well.

Comment: Extract a minimal example *before* posting a question here. See also https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I added the equals operator. The cout is showing me how the value of the schema stored with the key that corresponds to the first schemaFolder changes during each iteration (which is what I can't understand)

Comment: Again the biggest problem here is that for some this object is still available to be referenced when its been declared on a previous iteration. It should not even be something you shoudl be able to reference.

Comment: Note that the data from the variable of the previous iteration is stored in the same place as your new variable.

Comment: What happens if you run a debug-enabled version of your code?  When a variable goes out of scope, the destructor is run.  If the destructor does not touch the members, then if another object is created on top of the same memory, and doesn't change member values, then you'll see the remnants of the previous object.  Debug builds usually modify the memory occupied by the object during construction, so that you can catch this exact scenario.

Comment: So is the issue that putting the schema object into the map doesn't prevent it from going out of scope? I would assume that once something is inserted into a container that it no longer goes out of scope.